# Get the average Color of a Surface ignoring transparent pixels

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

My Image has a white background, which is set to invisible using `image.set_colorkey`.
I am trying to get the average color of the non-transparent pixels (in this case it only has one color).

`pygame.transform.average_color` doesn't work for me because it also takes the invisible white pixels, which leads to a very light shade of the color being returned (also the alpha of the returned color is 0, which i don't understand).

this is the image (white background, main color = (38, 43, 68))

[image]

this is the smallest code example i can think of:

```
image = pygame.image.load('enemy.png')
image.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
color = pygame.transform.average_color(self.image, self.image.get_rect())
# color = (171, 172, 182, 0)
```

Comment: How about you loop through every pixel and use Surface.get_at() to read the colors, implementing the average manually? It wouldn’t be a very performant operation, but it would work fine.

Comment: @Starbuck5 I thought of this but decided it was too slow. for my application I did a workaround but I was curios if there was any fast and easy way

Comment: were you running through it every frame? If the surface doesn't need to change, you don't need to recompute the average.

Comment: @Starbuck5 I only calculated it when an enemy was destroyed, and then it caused some lag (not much, but still annoying). Calculating it only once is a gerat idea. I should have thought of this myself. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to scale the color channels with the ratio of the number of pixels of the surface (*width* * *height*) and the number of opaque pixels. The number of pixels can be get with [`pygame.mask.Mask.count`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.count):

```py
def get_averqge_color(surf):
    color = pygame.transform.average_color(surf, surf.get_rect())
    pxiel_count = pygame.mask.from_surface(surf).count()
    scale = surf.get_width() * surf.get_height() / pxiel_count
    return (round(color[0]*scale), round(color[1]*scale), round(color[2]*scale))
```

Since the color channels are integer values, there are still some accuracy issues, however the result is close. See the example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

def get_averqge_color(surf):
    color = pygame.transform.average_color(surf, surf.get_rect())
    pxiel_count = pygame.mask.from_surface(surf).count()
    scale = surf.get_width() * surf.get_height() / pxiel_count
    print(color, scale, pxiel_count)
    return (round(color[0]*scale), round(color[1]*scale), round(color[2]*scale))

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 70)

test_surface = pygame.Surface((300, 300))
test_surface.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
pygame.draw.rect(test_surface, (255, 0, 0), (50, 50, 100, 100))
pygame.draw.rect(test_surface, (0, 255, 0), (150, 50, 100, 100))
pygame.draw.rect(test_surface, (255, 255, 0), (50, 150, 100, 100))
pygame.draw.rect(test_surface, (0, 0, 255), (150, 150, 100, 100))

avg_color = get_averqge_color(test_surface)
color_text = font.render(f"{avg_color[0]} {avg_color[1]} {avg_color[2]}", True, "black")

background = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
ts, w, h, c1, c2 = 80, *window.get_size(), (160, 160, 160), (96, 96, 96)
tiles = [((x*ts, y*ts, ts, ts), c1 if (x+y) % 2 == 0 else c2) for x in range((w+ts-1)//ts) for y in range((h+ts-1)//ts)]
[pygame.draw.rect(background, color, rect) for rect, color in tiles]

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    window.blit(background, (0, 0))
    rect = test_surface.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center)
    window.blit(test_surface, rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, "black", rect, 5, 5)
    window.blit(color_text, color_text.get_rect(center = rect.center))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: this works as long as the colorkey is black, because then all color values are 0 and don't mess up the average. however I was able to change this so it works for all colors as well. thank you.